# Rows exceeding margin in tabulary environment

Tags: tables, margins, tabulary

The main issue I am having is that the second column becomes squished and the table exceeds the 1 inch margin that exists. What's the best to fix the issue? I also need the table to have the table be as compact and clean as possible as the page limit on my assignment is five pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LCL}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Something Something} Implementation Plan by Time Period} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Time Period and Length} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Action Plan} \\
\cline{1-3}
\multirow{2}{*}{Short Run} & $1$ Day & The first day and something and something dummy text.... Now i'm going to keep on adding more text until I really really can't. Do you understand the words that are coming out of my mouth sir?\\
& $1$ Week & Begin  here and end there and theren begin here aaga.\\
\multirow{2}{*}{Medium Run} & $1$ Month & Then do this ya, do exactly taht sd;flkjas.\\
& $6$ Months & You think you can think dawg hun? hun? hun? \\
\multirow{1}{*}{Long Run} & $1$ Year & ;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes the margin issue but the second column is still squished `:(`. If you notice, the 1 is above "week" instead of being beside it.

Comment: I'm not sure but I did exactly what you said but I'm not getting the same result.

Comment: can you add more words in your code?

Comment: I edited the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put `\noindent` before `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LCL}`. Further, you can set the dimensions:

```
\tymin=.1\textwidth
\tymax=.7\textwidth
```

so as to get every thing properly. For details, refer to the `tabulary` manual (`texdoc tabulary` or [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net).

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\tymin=.1\textwidth
\tymax=.7\textwidth
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LCL}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Something Something} Implementation Plan by Time Period} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Time Period and Length} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Action Plan} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-5ex}{Short Run}} & $1$ Day & The first day and something and something dummy text.... Now i'm going to keep on adding more text until I really really can't. Do you understand the words that are coming out of my mouth sir?\\
& $1$ Week & Begin  here and end there and theren begin here aaga.\\
\multirow{2}{*}{Medium Run} & $1$ Month & Then do this ya, do exactly taht sd;flkjas.\\
& $6$ Months & You think you can think dawg hun? hun? hun? \\
\multirow{1}{*}{Long Run} & $1$ Year & ;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj; swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj; swelkj;swelkj; swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also note that the line

```
;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj;swelkj
```

needs some spaces in between so that the sentence gets broken across multiple lines. In addition, I used `\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-5ex}{Short Run}}` to adjust the vertical placement.

Comment: Wow. That is incredibly weird. It's working! Thanks! EDIT: When I add more words, the problem comes back.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks like it's working now! `:D`